# Calculating overtime work

Tags: php

Here's my code.

```
<p>You worked <?php echo $hours ?>hour(s) this week.</p>
<p>Your pay for the week is: <?php  $wage  = $_GET["wage"] * ($hours > 40 ? $hours * 1.5 : $hours);
;echo number_format("$wage",2); ?></p>
```

Thing about this is it calculated by 1.5 if it works over 40+ ..
But i want it like this. 
Lets say you work 41 hours.
I want 40 hours to be the standard rate
and the 1 hour is multiply by 1.5

How can i do that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like you have written in your question (not in your code):

```
$wage * ($hours > 40 ? 40 : $hours) + $wage * 1.5 * ($hours > 40 ? $hours - 40 : 0)
```

or, condensed:

```
$wage * ($hours > 40 ? 40 + ($hours-40)*1.5 : $hours)
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I deleted my comment with regards to the edit, but my point was that the first version is a bit complex, and doesn't follow the form of the code of the OP.  I wasn't suggesting it was wrong, just didn't leverage the commutative property of multiplication

Comment: @ernie: I deleted my comment when I realised you weren't the OP :) you're not wrong - this would be much clearer if broken out

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula in your if clause:

```
<p>Your pay for the week is: <?php  $wage  = $_GET["wage"] * ($hours > 40 ? ($hours-40) * 1.5 + 40: $hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this out procedurally so that it's clearer what you're doing:

```
<?php
$normal_wage  = $_GET["wage"];
$overtm_wage  = 1.5 * $normal_wage;

$normal_hours = min($hours, 40);
$overtm_hours = $hours - $normal_hours;

$total_pay    = ($normal_wage * $normal_hours) + ($overtm_wage * $overtm_hours);

echo "<p>You worked {$normal_hours} standard hour(s) and {$overtm_hours} overtime hour(s) this week (a total of {$hours} hours).</p>";

echo "<p>Your pay for the week is: £" . number_format($total_pay, 2) . "</p>";
?>
```

#### [Live demo](http://codepad.org/DRU74uvj)

There's no great benefit in PHP of writing your code in as few characters as possible, and in doing so you actually restrict maintainability.